# pgfplots: how to add a label to a graph with the option clip=true?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

### Question

I would like to add a label to my graph, on the right of it or at any other place, for instance somewhere above my graph.

Is it possible?

I want to use the option `clip=true`, because of the graph of `tan(x)` (see the picture below)

### Code and picture

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis x line = middle, 
axis y line = middle, 
domain=-2:2,
xmin = -2, 
xmax = 2,  
ymin=-10,
ymax=10,
grid = major, 
clip = false]
\addplot[color=orange, samples=100, smooth, ultra thick] {tan(deg(x))}  node[right] {$\tan$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I remove the options `ymin=...`, `ymax=...`, the output is fine, but I would like, if possible, to set the values of ymin and ymax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set `clip mode=individual` to clip only the plot lines. However, this also clips `node`s added at the end of the plot like in your code, as it is part of the same path. As a workaround you could add an empty, named node at the end of the plot, and place a new node at this location.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,  
    domain=-2:2,
    xmin = -2, 
    xmax = 2,  
    ymin=-10,
    ymax=10,
    grid = major, 
    clip = true,
    clip mode=individual]
\addplot[color=orange, samples=100, smooth, ultra thick] {tan(deg(x))}  node (endofplot) {};
\node [right,orange] at (endofplot) {$\tan(x)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for your help! As you might have guessed, I am writing a command to draw automatically functions on a graph!